# Good logging library for managed/unmanaged application?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, logging

What logging library or approach would you recommend for this case:

- We want to be able to log both from managed and unmanaged code
- For the unmanaged code, the implementation should not cross back into managed code, because this could cause our unmanaged threads to get 'caught' during a garbage collection.
- Performance is a concern

[NLog](http://www.nlog-project.org/) provides a "C" api, but implements it in terms of its managed implementation.

Many of the C logging libraries out there ([rlog](http://www.arg0.net/rlog), [glog](http://code.google.com/p/google-glog/)) are reliant on macros + preprocessing and are not amenable to wrapping with .NET without extensive modification.

I guess I'm looking for something with a native/unmanaged logging core, but a decent .NET managed api as well.  Does this exist?  If this doesn't exist, what comes the closest?

Followup - Thanks for the responses mentioning log4net.  I think Log4Net and NLog both perform ok in a pure managed application, -but-...  The app I've been asked to build has unmanaged I/O on a background thread that absolutely cannot afford to be stopped by a garbage collection.  If unmanaged c++ code has to call "up" into a managed logger, it stands a chance of being frozen for 200 or even 2000 milliseconds while the garbage collection occurs.  That's why I'm looking for a library that is unmanaged at its core. - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pantheios](http://pantheios.sourceforge.net/) might meet your requirements. It's open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html)?

I'm not sure if the core is unmanaged or managed, but I've seen it used in several .NET projects.

Comment: It's written in C#, so managed.

Answer (score 1):

I've made quite a bit of use of log4net in my C# and VB .Net projects. Haven't used it in C++ since I haven't done C++ since .Net & Java became my primary programming environments a few years ago. But having used log4j and log4net quite a bit I can vouch for both their performance and ease of use.

Links

**[log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)** Logging for C++ 
**[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)** Logging for .Net

Answer (score 0):

Can you somehow expose an unmanaged method to your managed .NET code so all of the logging is actually handled from the unmanaged side?

I have used the boost libraries for C++ and they worked well for me.